# Panel.Enabled works inside UpdatePanel. Panel.Visible does not

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a Panel control inside of an UpdatePanel. When I set Panel.Enabled = false; on postback, all controls inside the Panel become disabled. However, when I call Panel.Visible = false; on postback, the Panel still displays.

This code does as expected:

```
protected void rdoPayment_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlBillingAddress.Enabled = rdoCreditCard.Checked;
    upBillingAddress.Update();
}
```

If I change the code to this, the panel is still visible when it's set to false:

```
protected void rdoPayment_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlBillingAddress.Visible = rdoCreditCard.Checked;
    upBillingAddress.Update();
}
```

Further, if I change the code like so, when Enabled is set to false, the controls no longer become disabled and the panel is still visible:

```
protected void rdoPayment_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlBillingAddress.Enabled = rdoCreditCard.Checked;
    pnlBillingAddress.Visible = rdoCreditCard.Checked;
    upBillingAddress.Update();
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

ps. I can post the aspx portion of the code, but it's really long so I'll only post it if it's absolutely needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon closer inspection of the aspx, I realized that the Panel was actually wrapping the UpdatePanel instead of vice versa. I put the Panel inside of the ContentTemplate and all is well now.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The Panel's Visible property is returning true since its parent control's visibility is also set to true. This isn't well documented, but</s> here's a relevant blog post: [ASP.Net: Remember, the .Visible property also checks parent’s visibility!](http://www.pdsys.org/blog/post/2009/01/11/ASPNet-Remember-the-Visible-property-also-checks-parente28099s-visibility!.aspx)

<s>Perhaps you'll need to refactor your code and use a separate UpdatePanel for just that Panel and set the UpdatePanel's visibility instead. I suggest setting a breakpoint and checking the visibility after testing with different values for the control and its parent.</s>

While the above link seems accurate for the PlaceHolder control and others it seemed very odd if it applied to everything since this should be a common scenario. I got around to testing this and setting visibility to a Panel within an UpdatePanel works fine.

Comment: That wasn't exactly the problem, but it led me to it, so thanks!

Upon close inspection of the aspx, I realized that the Panel was actually wrapping the UpdatePanel instead of vice versa. I put the Panel inside of the <ContentTemplate> and all is well. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I've updated my post accordingly. I knew the visibility issue wasn't always applicable to other controls but it sounded like a possibility. Testing helped.